# vector - pair uniform initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std-pair, list-initialization

I have a collection defined as -

```
using Parameters = std::vector<int>;
using Group = std::pair<std::string, Parameters>;
std::vector<Group> inputs;
```

My intention is to use statements like

```
inputs.push_back(group0 /*What goes in here ?*/);
inputs.push_back(group1 /*What goes in here ?*/);
```

How can I initialize `group0` and `group1` using initializer list ?
This code like this doesn't seem to work

```
inputs.push_back(std::make_pair("group0", {1, 2, 3, 4}));
```

---

EDIT: There *are* already existing questions on vector-pair initialization but i couldn't see any where `second` of `std::pair` is again a collection.

Comment: Have a look at [`vector::emplace_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/). It does inplace construction i.e. you may pass the arguments directly and the instance of `Group` is constructed at the "final" storage place.

Answer (score 10):

When you write `inputs.push_back(std::make_pair("group0", {1, 2, 3, 4}))` you're asking `make_pair` to deduce the types of both its arguments. But the second argument, a *braced-init-list*, is not an expression, so it has no type. Hence, template argument deduction fails.

The easiest solution is to remove the call to `make_pair` and use *braced-init-lists* everywhere.

```
inputs.push_back({"group0", {1, 2, 3, 4}});
```

Now, list initialization will [enumerate available constructors](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list#1.2) and call the `pair` constructor with the outer pair of arguments, and the `vector` constructor for the inner *braced-init-list*.

Answer (score 1):

While

```
inputs.push_back({"group0", {1, 2, 3, 4}});
```

works correctly for what you intend to do, I think it is more expressive to use:

```
inputs.push_back(std::make_pair("group0", Parameters{1, 2, 3, 4}));
```